# ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS when sending document

Tags: docusignapi

My application lets a user connect their account via OAuth, then can send an envelope to a user based on a template. However, the send fails with a 400 response.

I am making two requests - one POST to create an envelope from a template (which receives a 201 response), and one PUT against the new envelope to send it with some tab data populated. However, the send call fails with the following 400 response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",
    "message": "The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."
}
```

---

The first call to create the envelope contains this body:

```
{
    "eventNotification": {
        "envelopeEvents": [
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
            }
        ],
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
        "includeTimeZone": "true",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
        "url": "https://mywebsite.com/webhook/receive/docusign"
    },
    "templateId": "a65ae540-16eb-4078-aab9-2dff5c2eda25",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "me@example.org",
            "name": "My Name",
            "roleName": "Employee"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the second (failing) call contains this body:

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "me@example.org",
                "name": "My Name",
                "recipientId": "92174826",
                "tabs": {
                    "fullnameTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "tabId": "eb0c7a2d-5912-4cf1-8e2b-fd17fd7fb63c",
                            "value": "My Name"
                        },
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "tabId": "92fb908c-6f84-472a-aa9d-baaa29758c12",
                            "value": "My Name"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Some values (names, emails etc) have been changed for privacy. The template contains a single recipient - Employee.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a "routingOrder" property with a different number.
You cannot have two recipients with the same email/name and the same routing order.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up refactoring my payload. Instead of building from an empty array, I call the API to describe recipients on the envelope, then change the parts of it I needed to change. So this would have included routing order.
The issue was creating the recipients in the first call, and updating them in the second was causing duplicates. I'm not sure how the Docusign system dedupes these recipients, but perhaps routing order contributes.
I just wish there were unique IDs for everything. It would be so much cleaner.